# display list in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a list of tuples which looks something like the following:

```
answer_guess_list = [('A',), ('B', 'C',), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D',)]
```

In my templates, I have a template variable with the same name.

```
{% for guess_list in answer_guess_list %}

        <p>
            {% for guess_value in guess_list %}
                {{ guess_value }}, # Notice the comma (,)
            {% endfor %}
        </p>

{% empty %}
    <p>Nothing to show.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

It displays the list as the following:

```
A,
B, C, 
A, B, C, D,
```

I don't want the terminal commas and rather display it as:

```
A
B, C
A, B, C, D
```

I do not know how to achieve that.
Could you help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be one way to do it:

```
{% for guess_list in answer_guess_list %}
    <p>
        {% for guess_value in guess_list %}
            {{ guess_value }}{% if forloop.counter < guess_list|length %}, {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
{% empty %}
    <p>Nothing to show.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Or you could also use the built-in template filter [join](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#join):

```
{% for guess_list in answer_guess_list %}
    <p>
        {{ guess_list|join:", " }}
    </p>
{% empty %}
    <p>Nothing to show.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked and also made me realise that I should read django documentation more often than I usually do.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Django documentation is awesome so it's a very good decision to try and read it more when you hit a roadblock.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) is the documentation for the template tags, the below is the tag it self.

```
@register.filter(name="my_filter")
def fltr(tpl):
    return ','.join([str(i) for i in tpl])
```

After registering this tag by following instructions at the docs, you can use it as:

```
    <p>
        {% for guess_value in guess_list %}
            {{ guess_value|my_filter }},
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks. It seems that template tags/filters can help me do that. But, aren't you still using comma at the end here `{{ guess_value|my_filter }},` ?

Comment: I have no idea why did you put it in your original template so I didn't temper with it, my point was only the filters.

Comment: Ok. I understand. My aim is to display the 'guess' the user has made for a particular problem.  Each list item (a tuple) is a guess. In the given example, A was the first guess followed by B and C as second guess and so on. Each guess should be displayed in separate lines. Each line should contain the guess made by user.

Comment: I see, now if you use that comma inside the template; it still is gonna display your unwanted comma; if you simply delete it from there you may not even need to use the filter. But if you see the comma even after you deleted it from the template; the filter would definitely solve it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `{{ guess_list|my_filter }}` since the function my_filter expects a tuple/list?

Comment: You already are giving it a tuple in my example; `for guess_value(tuple) in guess_list(tuple list)` so it is good to go.

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in option for this in [`for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) templatetag called `foorloop.last`. Simply change your code to this:

```
{% for guess_list in answer_guess_list %}
<p>
    {% for guess_value in guess_list %}
        {{ guess_value }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</p>
{% empty %}
<p>Nothing to show.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

and if for loop is last, trailing comma won't render.